# Zoom page with jQuery same as Ctrl + mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, zooming, ctrl

I am new to jQuery.
I am trying figure out whether I can solve a problem I have with jQuery.

What I want to do is simulate Ctrl + mouse scroll (page zoom) event via jQuery.

Can this be done with jQuery.

Really appreciate any help on this ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Mouse Wheel Zooming for a Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925573/javascript-mouse-wheel-zooming-for-a-web-page)

Comment: Have you googled? Because there is a good amount of questions regarding this already, also please show us what you have tried and what is not working for you.

Comment: I tried to do something like this.  var e = jQuery.Event("mousewheel");
  e.ctrlKey = true;
  $(document).trigger(e);

Comment: The event is getting fired. Not really sure what else I need to pass to the function. I assume I have pass things like scroll amount ?